# Nomenclature of icons e.g. Kebab, Meatball, Hamburger

Tags: icons, names, graphic-design, nomenclature

Is there any logic behind naming icons in UX ? e.g. Breadcrumbs, meatball, kebab, hamburger, doner.

Possible logic of the name "breadcrumbs": *It helps the user find a "page's location" similar to how it is used to lead a rat to a specific location (a rat trap in this case).*

Is there similar (maybe funny as well) logic behind naming icons like meatball, kebab, etc ?

Comment: Meatball, kebab, hamburger and such are named after what they visually look like. Breadcrumbs are named so as they act as a metaphor (leaving breadcrumbs on the ground to find your way back, like in the fairy tale).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Explanation of hamburger and kebab menus, along with other examples](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/115469/41948)

Answer (score 1):

The term "Breadcrumbs" doesn't refer to an icon, but to a set of [hierarchical links that show the user the location of the current page in relation to the site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_navigation). The term itself is a reference to the fairy tale of [Hansel and Gretel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_and_Gretel).

As for the others, they are all named because they look like real world items.
 The "hamburger" icon kinda looks like a hamburger. Three vertical dots looks kinda like a kabab. And so on and so forth...